# NullException when try to pass data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, bundle

Something weird: i'm trying to pass data from Profile activity  to VewPostFragment:
The code in activity is:

```
private String s=" ";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        ProfileUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_name);

        test();
        ViewPostFragment fragment = ViewPostFragment.newInstance("Your value");
    }
 private void test()
    {
        ViewPostFragment mFragment=new ViewPostFragment();
                                Bundle args=new Bundle();
                                args.putString("PostKeyS" , s);
                                mFragment.setArguments(args);
    }
```

I check if the "s" data is not null

in the fragment my code is:

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_post,container,false);


        mBackArrow=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.backArrow);



        String value = getArguments().getString("PosKeyS");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TThe code is the same?" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;

    }
public static ViewPostFragment newInstance(String s) {
        ViewPostFragment fragment = new ViewPostFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("PostKeyS", s);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

and i always get error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.bluesky, PID: 22380
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.bluesky/com.example.android.bluesky.Profile.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2406)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.android.bluesky.ViewPostFragment.onCreateView(ViewPostFragment.java:91)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                      at com.example.android.bluesky.Profile.ProfileActivity.onStart(ProfileActivity.java:115)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1224)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6032)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22380 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling `String ss = getArguments().getString("PostKeyS");` from constructor?

Comment: I've tried some different ways, but always got same error

Comment: Can you please add the rest of the code from your `ViewPostFragment` class?

Comment: Hi, i just added the rest of the code, according to answer below...

Comment: Ok, if you read the `stacktrace` carefully you can see that the error is quite more far reaching, can you please show the rest of code? How are you showing the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You should use newInstance method for this

firstly you must add this method in your fragment

```
public static ViewPostFragment newInstance(String s) {
    ViewPostFragment fragment = new ViewPostFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("PostKeyS", s);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

then you must send the data in the activity like this

```
ViewPostFragment fragment = ViewPostFragment.newInstance("Your value");
```

finally you can get the data in your fragment like this

```
String value = getArguments().getString("PosKeyS");
```

Comment: You are using PostKey when getting the PostKeyS data while sending. Could this be the problem @DimaBokov

Answer (score 0):

I've asked you to post the rest of your `ViewPostFragment` because my guess is the issue is outside of the code you provided (I'll update this answer if needed).

From the provided context is not directly related the way you are passing the data around.

As you stated you are trying to do the `Toast` on the `onCreateView()` method.

**Since this is a fragment do it on the `onViewCreated()` instead** (this also depends on what `Fragment` superclass your fragment extends from the support version or the (deprecated) framework.

I also recommend you reading these 3-minute articles to help you clear up the way you pass data around:

- [[AndroidBits] How to decouple navigation between your components](https://blog.joaquimley.com/androidbits-how-to-decouple-navigation-between-your-views-4c50659379d9)
- [[AndroidBits] Passing data in Android](https://blog.joaquimley.com/androidbits-passing-data-in-android-6cec1917bdc)

Comment: Hi, thanks for links, but it's not works...
The best way i think is to use Bundle, but for some reason it's not works at all:((